# Cassandra is OOMing when reading from spark

Tags: cassandra, out-of-memory, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to read all data of my table with spark to do a simple counting.

But some Cassandra nodes in my cluster throw `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. After this, my spark job stops because it cannot contact these specific nodes any more.

An easy solution would be to raise the amount of heap memory, but I think that it just masking the real problem.

The heap dump reveals that there is a lot of `SSTableScanner` instances (7200) in two `ArrayList`'s, which altogether represent 35% of the memory. The third biggest object seems to be the cache (org.apache.cassandra.cache.ConcurrentLinkedHashCache) with 8% of the total memory.

- I was wondering if I had this problem because one of the rows is too wide

  - ( I know my biggest partition is 8G large ).
- Or is it because there are too many SSTables.

  - (varying between 4K and 22K)

Because the read is sequential I was expecting Cassandra not to load every `SSTable` at once, but just the one that it needs. But it's also possible it has to look at a specific token range across all `SSTables`.

Is there something that can identify the underlying problem, or a special configuration that keeps less `SSTable`'s in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably hit
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9754
Having huge C* partitions or huge SStable count is not good in common case especially for scan requests

Comment: Yes, I know but how to change schema if I cannot read my datas?
And as I said my problem is not index info but SSTableScanner

Comment: Compaction usually help, especially if you can temporary increase memory limits, then  materialized view can be used to rearrange the schema for reading.

Comment: I use cassandra 2.1.2 :x